# Can't import symbol from namespace shared across two packages

Tags: python, conda

I have two packages - `corpo-common-utils` and `corpo-utils`, with same root namespace `corpo.util`. Also I have package `corpo-ui` that depends on class from `corpo-utils` package. When I run script that uses `corpo-ui`, it shows me following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Thing' from 'corpo.util' (my/path/to/conda/env/site-packages/corpo-common-utils/corpo/util/__init__.py)
```

I'm using conda, python 3.7, code is isolated in conda environment.

In `corpo-commons`, every folder (`corpo`, `util`) contains `__init__.py` with following:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Same holds for `corpo` folder of `corpo-utils`. In `util` folder this line is present, after that there are imports of symbols that are exposed by the package.

Questions:

- what is the root cause of such behavior? Does `corpo-commons` hide `corpo-utils`?
- how can I fix this?

Comment: from the question it appears you have `util` but you are using `utils`. could be typo

Comment: @Macintosh_89 , typo, indeed, thanks!